# Writing Java nested if statement for Excel nested if statement?

Tags: java, nested, excel-formula

I am trying to convert an excel nested IF statement into code language, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly and was hoping I could get some help

Here is the excel statement :

```
=IF(D3="Feather",IF(OR(I3>1000,R3="n/a"),"",IF(W3="F","F",IF(AND(I3<=1000,R3>8),"F","P"))),"")
```

My code :

```
if( D3 == "Feature"){
   if (I3>1000 || R3 =="n/a") {

   } else if (W3=="F"){
       "F"  
   } else if( I3<=1000 && R3>8){
       "F"
   } else {
       "P"
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The Java ternary operator (consisting of `?` and `:` characters) is a better match to the Excel `IF` function than a Java `if/else` construct.  You might do well to read up on it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But my problem is that I don't have much proficiency with excel statements, so I am not sure if I am interpreting correctly. I first need to understand the excel statement correctly before using the ternary operators

Comment: I've re-opened this.  It's really NOTHING LIKE the question that it was closed as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed interpreted the Excel formula correctly, but there are three things that stop your code from being "correct Java".

- Expressions like `"P"`, `"F"` and so on don't really have any effect sitting by themselves between `{` and `}`.  The thing about the Excel formula is that it actually has a value; and that's something that a series of Java `if` and `else` statements don't actually have.  If you want a value, you could either write all of this as a Java method that returns a value, or you could use the ternary operator `? :` to create a single expression with the value that you desire.
- To compare strings in Java, you almost always want to use the `equals` method, instead of the `==` operator.  The reason is that two different `String` objects might have the same value; but in this case, `==` will return `false` for them, but `equals` will return true.
- It's not clear what type `R3` is.  At one point, you treat it as if its type were `String`, and at another point, you treat it as a numeric variable.  Unlike Excel formulas, any expression in Java has a well defined data type.

Translating the formula into a Java expression, and being careful of these three issues, we get something like this.

```
d3.equals("Feather") ? 
    ((i3 > 1000 || r3.equals("n/a")) ? "" : 
      w3.equals("F") ? "F" : 
      (i3 <= 1000 && Integer.parseInt(r3) > 8) ? "F" : "P" ) : ""
```

But this is a bit hard to read, because there are too many ternary operators.  Most people would prefer to write this as a method, something like this.

```
public String excelFormula(String d3, int i3, String r3, String w3) {
    if (d3.equals("Feather")) {
        if (i3 > 1000 || r3.equals("n/a")) {
            return "";
        } else if (w3.equals("F")) {
            return "F";
        } else if (i3 <= 1000 && Integer.parseInt(r3) > 8) {
            return "F";
        } else {
            return "P";
        }
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```